# Fake Chromium showing on launchpad and won't uninstall

Tags: launchpad, virus

My colleague has noticed there is a Chromium icon on their launchpad screen but it's not possible to remove it. We've tried dragging it to the Trash but nothing happens.

There is no app listing in /Applications

Is it a virus? If so what's the best way to remove it?

Comment: How did you drag it to the trash from inside Launchpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check System Profiler → Software → Applications to see if you have it installed somewhere else. You can see where it's installed to by looking at the "Location" tag.

[image]

If it looks fishy, I'd recommend downloading [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com) and running a scan to see if there's anything fishy.